# How can I configure Windows Explorer to use a single icon?

Tags: windows-7, windows-explorer, icons

Windows explorer uses one program icon for Computer, a different icon for drive C:, another for folders and files, and yet others for libraries. (I am not talking about the icons inside Windows Explorer, I'm talking about the icon you see on the taskbar or Alt-Tab).

When I use Alt-Tab or glance at the taskbar, I would like to see a single, recognizable icon for Windows Explorer. Is it possible to configure Windows Explorer to use a single program icon no matter what you're looking at?

Answer (score 0):

You can pin it to the taskbar, and then it will always be the same, no matter what folder.
(and it will always be at quick access on your taskbar)

Comment: No, it is not the same. Even if you pin it to the taskbar, the icon on the taskbar and in alt-Tab changes, depending on what is being viewed in Windows Explorer. (I normally use the windows-E shortcut to open Windows Explorer.)